# How to detect if an element is in dragging state with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui

I have a button (`#call_plugin_wrapper`) with content inside it (`#call_plugin_inner`).

I want the inner part to become unclickable when the parent is being dragged, how do I achieve this using jQuery?

```
$('#call_plugin_wrapper').draggable();
$('#call_plugin_inner').click(function() {...}

var widget_drag = false;

$('#call_plugin_wrapper').draggable({
   axis: "y",
   start: function() {
      widget_drag = true;
   },
   stop: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
         widget_drag = false;
      }, 100);
   }
});

$('#call_plugin_inner').click(function() {
   if (widget_drag == false) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var widget_drag = false;

$('#call_plugin_wrapper').draggable({ axis: "y", start: function(){widget_drag=true;}, 
    stop: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){widget_drag=false;},100);
    } 
});

$('#call_plugin_inner').click(function() {
    if (widget_drag==false){...}
```